# Database side transactions split vs Application side transactions split

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, synchronization

I'm working on a C# + SqlServer application whick handles massive data loads.

At the moment our main issue involves a massive, single transaction `DELETE` operation: DBAs suggested to split this single monolitic transaction into many transactions, in order to achive following results:

1. smaller transaction log
2. fewer row to rollback in case of timeout error
3. fewer sincronization/lock problems, due to reduced transaction time

(In our scenario is not a problem to give up atomicity of the single transaction: semantically we could perform a `TRUNCATE` but we can't, because we are filtering rows to be deleted)

I'm wondering if there is any difference, in terms of transaction management and synchronization, between issuing a single (Transact)SQL statement, containing a loop like

```
SET @r = 1;
WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TX;

  DELETE TOP (100000)
    [OUR_BIG_TABLE]
    WHERE ...;

  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;

  COMMIT TX;
END
```

and looping in application (C#) code, issuing multiple `DELETE TOP(100000) ...` in different, client-handled transactions.

My feeling is that the single-SQL statement has better performance, due to reduced network roundtrip.
I have doubts instead about synchronization/locking between my deletion activity and other, concurrent activities on the same table; so, my question specifically is: **is there any difference between the approaches above in terms of the possibility, for transactions issued by another client, to interleave between transactions issued by our process**?

I think there is no difference (from the point of view stated above) between the proposed approaches, since client-controlled transactions are equivalent to `BEGIN TX` ... `COMMIT TX` statements, but I prefer a confirmation by who knows more than me...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Short answer - you are correct but the performance difference might not be significant. I will point out that your loop will never execute. Look closely.

Comment: One can argue that there is little point to using a transaction at all for each individual delete (a single statement is atomic). You will probably need a different recovery solution if the delete logic fails at any point - but only you can judge that. And I hope someone will test this failure scenario.

Comment: Thank you @SMor, I changed initial value of `@r`...

Comment: How do you filter the data? By time? Some other attribute? You could use table partitions and simply remove the partitions with older data when needed, instead of trying to perform a big delete operation. Partitions are available in all editions since SQL Server 2016 SP1. They were an Enterprise-only feature in previous versions